# Not a functor not prefunctor

Tags: terminology, category-theory

Are there any special term for the following?

*A function from the set of morphisms of a category to the set of morphisms of an other category preserving source and destination of every morphism.*

I imply that the sets of morphisms of the two categories are the same.

Note that my functions are not functors, not even prefunctors.

Comment: I imply that the sets of morphisms of the two categories are the same.

Comment: Please, add all relevant information to the body of the question, Porton.It is better if people reading do nothave to read all comments to find out what you implied.

Comment: So you are just dropping the requirement that a functor preserves the identity and respects compositions?

Comment: Willie Wong♦: It is just not a functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morphism of graphs. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: A morphism of graphs may not preserve source or destination.

Comment: @porto: a morphism of graphs which is the identity on obejcts... *Not everything has a name*.

Comment: Porton-Suárez functors. No it does.